# Unity - Coroutine works differently in Android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a coroutine that executes code at a certain interval. For some reason, when I run it in the Unity editor, it counts the time correctly, but as soon as I run the same code on android, the coroutine starts counting the time 2-3 times slower. I don't have any checks for what operating system. What could be the problem?

Code:

```
IEnumerator StraveTimer()
{
    while (straveTime < maxStraveTime)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.003f);
        straveTime += 0.01f;
    }
    StopCoroutine("StraveTimer");
    straveTime = 0;
}
```

Comment: [The docs say that the `WaitForSeconds` argument is multiplied by `Time.timeScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) - so what is the value of `Time.timeScale` on Android vs. your PC? You can use `WaitForSecondsRealtime`, but be aware that those methods will never be precise or exact - you will need to use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`  to do precise timing. (And don't use `DateTime` either, that's also imprecise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general a

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.003f);`
```

makes little sense! I highly doubt your app runs with 300+ frames per second on your phone. So either way you will at least wait one frame - which might be longer than expected with a "normal" frame-rate of 60 fps one frame takes about `0.017` seconds - you can as well just use

```
yield return null;
```

And then the resulting main issue is that you increase your value framerate dependent by `0.01` per frame.

Also there is no need to use `StopCoroutine` here.

Your routine could simply be

```
IEnumerator StraveTimer()
{
    while (straveTime < maxStraveTime)
    {
        yield return null;
        straveTime += INCREASE_PER_SECOND * Time.deltaTime;
    }
 
    straveTime = 0;
}
```