# IEnumerator with delays is running in the wrong order on Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have subtitles and voiceovers on my project. I want to delay all chars on the string with sync with sound. Then I write this code, which is working fine in the editor:

```
public void Sync(GameObject textGameObject, string textCurrent, AudioClip clip)
{

    audioDuration = clip.length;

    textArea = textGameObject.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
    textArea.text = "";  //delete current text
    subs = textCurrent.ToCharArray();
    textDuration = clip.length / subs.Length;

    audioSource.PlayOneShot(clip);
   
    StartCoroutine(DelayTexts());
}

private IEnumerator DelayTexts()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(textDuration);
    if (index < subs.Length)
    {
        textArea.text += subs[index];
        index++;
        StartCoroutine(DelayTexts());
    }
    else
    {
        StartCoroutine(WaitReadTime());
    }
}

private IEnumerator WaitReadTime()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    textArea.text = "";
    audioSource.Stop();
    index = 0;
}
```

This code works in the wrong order on Android, but i dont know why.I think `IEnumerator` is causing the problem. Can i do this without `IEnumerator` or fix the working order ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time issues can come into play. [Check out this link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/problem-with-coroutine-in-android.520803/) and also [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71186343/unity-coroutine-works-differently-in-android) to see what I mean. You'll need to add some debugging lines to track the index and subs values when running on device.

As a sidenote, I would recommend restructuring your DelayTexts method. It is not necessary to recursively call an IEnumerator this way. You can write your logic to loop instead.

Something like this. I'm not certain how your conditions work, so this may not be exactly what you'd want, but this is a better format.

```
  while (index < subs.Length)
  {
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(textDuration);

      textArea.text += subs[index];
      index++;
  }

  StartCoroutine(WaitReadTime());
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will let you know after i try.

Comment: I was looking for the solution without recursive method.This worked for me thanks!
I think problem on android was recursive method destroy the memory and cause delay.

Comment: @Rigidbody if it worked, I'd sure appreciate you accepting it as the answer :)